# How to select a specific card from a list of cards in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I have a set of cards taken from React Native base library. I want to select a unique card from it. I have not found any property of card like 'id' similar to html.

Home.js

```
 return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Body>
            <Title>Scanner</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
         <Content style= {{backgroundColor: '#cdc9c9'}}>
          <Card style= 
            {{width:100,height:100,backgroundColor:this.state.bgclr }} >
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                    Slot: 1A
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            </Card>
            <Card style={{width:100,height:100}} >
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                    Slot: 1B
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            </Card>
            <Card style={{width:100,height:100}}>
            <CardItem bordered>
              <Body>
                <Text>
                    Slot: 1C
                </Text>
              </Body>
            </CardItem>
            </Card>
            </Content> 
           <Button block success onPress={
             () => Alert.alert(this.setState({
             bgclr: 'green'}))}>
          <Text>Simulate Scan</Text>
          </Button>
          <Footer/>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Can you share the repo link from where you are using this component? I looked in the official docs and couldn't find the Card or Container components.

Comment: @HAK https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-def-headref

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store the cards in an array form, then refer to it on the render.

```
var cards = [
    <Card style= 
        {{width:100,height:100,backgroundColor:this.state.bgclr }} >
        <CardItem bordered>
          <Body>
            <Text>
                Slot: 1A
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
    </Card>,
    <Card style={{width:100,height:100}} >
        <CardItem bordered>
          <Body>
            <Text>
                Slot: 1B
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
    </Card>,
    <Card style={{width:100,height:100}}>
        <CardItem bordered>
          <Body>
            <Text>
                Slot: 1C
            </Text>
          </Body>
        </CardItem>
    </Card>
]
```

You can refer to it inside your return method, by using `{cards}` in place of your initial `Card` elements (or `{this.cards}`, or `{this.props.cards}`, depending on how you are storing the `cards` variable)

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Header>
      <Body>
        <Title>Scanner</Title>
      </Body>
      <Right />
    </Header>
    <Content style= {{backgroundColor: '#cdc9c9'}}>
      {cards}
    </Content> 
    <Button block success onPress={
         () => Alert.alert(this.setState({
         bgclr: 'green'}))}>
      <Text>Simulate Scan</Text>
    </Button>
    <Footer/>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: How do we render an array and also retrieve the particular values?

Comment: Edited based on your question

Comment: Thanks a lot. But cards is an array, So how do we retrieve the first element or any specific element from it. I'm new to react so I don't have an idea about rendering an array

Comment: Rendering an array would just works as if the elements of the array are stated one-by-one. As for retrieving the specific elements, you could do that by `cards[i]` with `i` being the element on index `i` in the array.